# pythonで、画像（JPEG）上にグラフを描画する方法について

Tags: python, python3, windows, 画像

マイナスからプラスの範囲の値をとるグラフを画像の上に重ねて表示・保存させたいのですが、以下のようなプログラムだと添付図のような結果になってしまいます。

画像全体にぴったり合うようにグラフを重ね（グラフのサイズに画像のサイズを合わせます）、かつグラフの目盛はそのまま保持させるにはどうすればよいのか教えていただきたいです。

```
img = Image.open("test.jpg")
img_rs = img.resize((200, 100))
img_draw = np.array(img_rs)

x = [-80,-65,-32,-13,-4,1,7,27,55,71,94]
y = [-47,-32,-27,-18,-9,3,9,21,34,41,49]
plt.plot(x, y, '-ro')
plt.xlim(-100, 100)
plt.ylim(-50,50)

plt.imshow(img_draw)
```

[image: プログラムの実行結果]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

画像を表示する時に`extent`を設定すると表示位置を設定できます。

```
img = Image.open("test.jpg")
img_rs = img.resize((200, 100))
img_draw = np.array(img_rs)

x = [-80,-65,-32,-13,-4,1,7,27,55,71,94]
y = [-47,-32,-27,-18,-9,3,9,21,34,41,49]
plt.plot(x, y, '-ro')
plt.xlim(-100, 100)
plt.ylim(-50,50)

extent = [-100, 100,-50,50]
plt.imshow(img_draw, extent=extent)
```